# BEGIN IMMEDIATE in sqlx or database/sql (golang)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, go, sqlx

How do you start a sqlite BEGIN IMMEDIATE transaction in jmoiron/sqlx or database/sql (for golang)? As per the docs, the `begin` methods allow you to control isolation methods (for example, https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Begin). However, the isolation method, if I'm not mistaken, is not what I'm looking for. As per the sqlite docs, transactions default to *DEFERRED* which result in deadlocks and race conditions for my use case, so I really need to ensure that it's BEGIN IMMEDIATE.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this other than at the connection level (you can specify the [`_txlock`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3#SQLiteDriver.Open) parameter).

I've opened [#400](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/400) to track adding this.